# Multiple authors' affiliations

Tags: titles, affiliation

I am using Texmaker 5.0.2 to write a paper. I have multiple authors'  affiliations I tried to solve it as the following:

```
\documentclass{cai}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
 \page{1}

\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}

\title{title}

\author
       {$^1$ first\surname {Author}, $^2$ Second\surname {Author}, $^3$ Third \surname {Author}, $^4$ Fourth\surname {Author}}

\affiliation{$^1^$, $^3$ First University\\
$^2$ Second University\\
$^4$ Third University\\
}

\email{$^1$ first@first.org, $^2$ second@second.com,\\\hspace{13mm}  $^3$ third@third.org,
       $^4$ fourth@foueth.com}


\noreceived{} \nocommunicated{}

\maketitle
```

but when I build it I get the following error

```
"! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \maketitle"
```

Maybe it is due to the special characters ($,^). Any help?
I appreciate any help you provide.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Superscripts are supposed to appear in math-mode only, that's why TeX says that there's a missing `$`. Replacing `^1` by `$^1$` should make the error go away. But many journal classes have built-in macros to provide the author's affiliations, so you shouldn't need to resort to `$^1$`. Please provide us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including the `\documentclass{}` you are using so we can tell you the best way to do that.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik have a look I provide the piece of code which I think the error in it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This `cai` document class you are using defines the `\author`, `\affiliation`, and `\email` macros such that you call it once for each author, like this:

```
\documentclass{cai}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
 \page{1}

\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}

\title{title}

\author{First \surname{Author}}
\affiliation{First University}
\email{first@first.org}

\author{Second \surname{Author}}
\affiliation{Second University}
\email{second@second.com}

\author{Third \surname{Author}}
\affiliation{First University}
\email{third@third.com}

\author{Fourth \surname{Author}}
\affiliation{Third University}
\email{fourth@fourth.com}

\noreceived{} \nocommunicated{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```